# Unable to migrate data from Ms Access to MySQL workbench using c# "SQL syntax error at Line 1"

Tags: c#, ms-access, mysql-workbench

i have been trying to solve this exception for a few days now but there is no luck in finding it. I am currently trying to transfer data from MS Access to MySQL workbench using C# application

The following error pop out at this line

```
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

with the exception saying that

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax  , find the right syntax to use
>   near **'V REG. 5V,
>   0.5A','','Yusuf','',''),('QFN','N230285000','Component','80','Storage' at line 1 "**

Below is the code where the error occurred. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
private void InsertDatatoTable(DataTable dt_Tbl)
    {
        MySqlConnection mConnection = null;
        try
        {
            string currenttime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");                
            StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("REPLACE INTO `inventorysystem` (`Product_Name`,`Product_ID`,`Product_Category`,`Quantity`,`Location`,`Manufacturer`,`Project _Name`,`Description`,`MinQuantity`,`Owner`,`QR_Code`,`Color_Type`) VALUES ");
            using (mConnection = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data_store"].ToString()))  
            {
                List<string> Rows = new List<string>();

                for (int i = 0; i < dt_Tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    Rows.Add(string.Format("('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}','{11}')", dt_Tbl.Rows[i][0].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][1].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][2].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][3].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][4].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][5].ToString(),
                        dt_Tbl.Rows[i][6].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][7].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][8].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][9].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][10].ToString(), dt_Tbl.Rows[i][11].ToString(), currenttime));
                }
                sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
                sCommand.Append(";");
                mConnection.Open();
                using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand.ToString(), mConnection))
                {
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Comment: Maybe start with removing the apostrophes from the first half of SQL statement.

Comment: So what have you tried to debug this error? The error is clear that something is wrong with the SQL.  Have you inspected the value of `sCommand` after the string is built?  Have you verified that the SQL syntax is valid?  The code tells some of the story, but that's very complicated when the SQL string should tell the story and make any errors more obvious.  That's what you should look at and/or share as part of the question.

Comment: @June7 , thank for replying , the apostrophes is actually a back tick that i found while searching for another error because some of the data have space between the word

Comment: Table and field names do not need apostrophe (or back tick) delimiter. If names have spaces or punctuation/special characters (exception of underscore) then use `[ ]` to delimit names. Doesn't matter if data has spaces. Also, appears to be a space in `Project _Name` that should not be there. And back tick is not recognized by SQL anyway.

Comment: @CPerkins , i am new to MySQL , so i am not sure whether the method that i used for debug is correct. I use breakpoint in c#

Comment: @June7 i did what you said by using the [ ] for delimit. But a different error come out said SQL syntax near Product_name , Product_ID and so on..
I hope this is understandable

Comment: Sorry, you will have to debug. I am just learning C# myself after many years of Access and VBA. I know correct syntax for SQL but not C# coding.

Comment: @June7 Is ok , I am glad that you are trying to help. So does this mean the error i have to look through the query and access?

Comment: You should somehow debug output the entire constructed SQL statement to see what it looks like and post that for review - edit the question.

Comment: @june7 I have found the issue, turns out the the c# is unable to pull a data that have special character such as ' or ` .

Answer (score 0):

Comment verifies suspicion I meant to ask about. Data containing apostrophes (`O'Hare`) or quotes (`sand at 5" depth`) will cause SQL query statement constructed in code to fail. This is not strictly a C# issue. Query statements built in any language will have to deal with this. In VBA use Replace function to double up apostrophe which forces SQL engine to treat as actual text, not special character (known as 'escaping' special character). Example:

`strSQL = "INSERT INTO tablename(fieldname) VALUES('" & Replace(Me.tbxLName, "'", "''") & "')"`

A quote character is trickier. So tricky that when I first encountered this issue, I gave up and instructed my users to not use quote character. I have since learned how to handle.

`Replace(Me.tbxComment, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))`

I presume there would be similar functionality in C#.